# Imported Network Manager settings doesn't show

Tags: debian, networkmanager

I wanted to transfer Network Manager settings from one machine to another. Both machines are running the Stable branch of Debian with MATE desktop, fully updated. I simply copied everything from

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

on one machine to that same folder on the other machine. I fixed up permissions and ownership to match the connection files I created on the second machine.

However, not even a single one of these *imported* connections show up in the GUI applet. When I try *nmcli* or *nmtui*, several of them actually show up as they should, but only a few of them. I checked all the permissions.

Any idea?

EDIT: I am an idiot. So, for anyone who would need it: You must check permissions and ownership for these files, contents of the "permissions=" line and of course, permission of the "system-connections" folder itself.

Comment: Update: after several reboots, wired connection profiles showed up in the "change connection" window. Updating them with the second machine's network interfaces instead of the first one's made them work properly. I have no success with Wi-Fi and VPN profiles yet.

Comment: Update #2: permissions= line is also correct - my username is the same on both machines